# An image with both transparent and semi-transparent parts

Tags: css, image, transparency

I want to create an image with transparent and semi-transparent parts in it, so that if I give, say color x as background, the transparent part will show X color and the semi-transparent part will show a gradient shade of the color X.

I need such an image to use in templates that will be used by clients who'll have different color themes.

Edit: Question is how to create both transparent & semi-transparent parts in an image ? Any pointers please.

Edit:
I'm making my question more clear. In the attached image, there is a transparent area. Idea was to have a transparent area as well a semi transparent area (area towards the pointer, currently this is not semi-transparent) in a image, so that if I give red as bg color, the transparent area will show red color & the semi-transparent area will show a gradient shade of red. I want to know how to make the area near the pointer as semi-transparent in gimp. Any ideas please.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the question? Have you tried? PNG supports alpha transparency (except in IE6, but there are fixes for that).

Comment: PNG images in modern browsers will do that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Answer (score 0):

Use a PNG-24 image and set the `background-color` of the element that holds it:

```
<div id="header" style="background-color: #f00"></div>

<style>
    #header {
        background: transparent url("header-background.png") no-repeat 50% 0;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

The inline color will override the `transparent` color from the CSS, and the solid color will be underneath the image.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. How to convert this png to png-24 format? https://dev.avvio.com/svn_convert/arrow.png

Comment: Tried your idea with the above png. The inline color shows in place of transparent area but the solid color doesnt show at all. Its not the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it in pure css you might break up the picture and then style it together like a pusle, And then give each brick a class which you style with different opacity

```
.test {
background-color: #6374AB;
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
}

.opaque1 {  // for all other browsers
    opacity: .5;
}

.opaque2 {  // for IE5-7
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.opaque3 {  // for IE8
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

IE compatibility note

If you want opacity to work in all IE versions, the order should be:

```
.opaque {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  // second!
}
```

***[Reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html).***

Comment: In this way your able to do it with multiple pictures without each picture needs to be redone everytime. So lets say you have 100 pictures, and you dicide 80% opacity wasn't right but 70 was then this is what i recommend